# where is subsonic 2.* documentation

Tags: subsonic

I have to get up to speed with subsonic 2.* to support an existing application. The subsonicproject website has a few walk-throughs but I was hoping to find something more complete. For instance, I don't see any mention of how to create a new record using subsonic.

Thank you,

Myron

Comment: Please note I'm looking for documentation, not specifically how to create a record.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Official documentation can be found [here](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page), under the heading "SubSonic 2.2 (for .NET 2.0 and up)".  However, I'm sure you have seen that it is woefully inadequate.

You may be better served by checking through [Rob Conery's blog](http://blog.wekeroad.com/category/subsonic).  SubSonic 2.* content starts [somewhere in 2007](http://blog.wekeroad.com/category/subsonic/page/10/).

Comment: Umm... which is all linked up to in the question I posted below

Answer (score 5):

Start here:
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/ActiveRecord

Then just go down the list:
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_2.x

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Query_Tool
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Command_line

The whole idea was to make it really, really simple to do things. People expect to have to read reams of docs to get into it - you don't. It's supposed to be a simple thing.

Comment: This domain is now controlled by someone using it for scamming/phishing. I do not recommend clicking on these links.